# An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: heroku, build, rubygems, pg, gemfile

I'm trying to deploy Zipsell with heroku. However when I run through the heroku and ruby setup and try to deploy via:

```
git clone https://github.com/yongfook/zipsell
cd zipsell
./bin/setup
```

I get the error message:

> **An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.**
>
> **Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.0.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.**

```
In Gemfile:
  pg
```

I have run through the setup process now multiple times and reinstalled all but still am not able to deploy. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: you need to install `pg` as your database. Are you using `sqlite`? Can you show your `Gemfile`.

Comment: when I run bundle check I get the following:

The following gems are missing
 * pg (1.0.0)
 * puma (3.12.0)
 * sprockets (3.7.2)
 * sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
 * rails (5.2.1)
 ...

When I then run bundle install I receive the error message as well.
Running gem install pg -v'1.0.0' I receive:
Error installing pg:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: again, share your `Gemfile`, you might need to install those gems.

Comment: Hey Steven, thanks for your reply. Abosulte bginner here so what is the command to show the compete gemfile? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `Gemfile` is a file in your project. Is where all the dependencies of the project are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the repo you posted it seems the error message is very clear. From the Gemfile of the repo you shared it seems you haven't install `pg` which is the [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/) (You will need to remove `sqlite`.

The problem is that there are some missing dependencies that you don't have installed and that why the error is thrown. There is the concepts of `gems` which is packaged code. https://rubygems.org/ via the following website you can find some of the gems you'r missing. There is also the versions which have to be compatible.

What you'll do is search for the missing `gems` shown in the error message. Check for the correct version if you the gem in your `Gemfile` but the version is conflicting.

https://github.com/yongfook/zipsell/blob/master/Gemfile

`bundle update`

install the missing gems

`gem install pg`
 and so on. Or do it straight in the Gemfile.

Comment: Hey thanks! This pointed me into the right direction. I found another post stating the following which solved my problem on MAC:
If you are not sure where your pg_config is, and assuming you are on Linux or Mac, you can run the following command:

which pg_config
this will return ==>  /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config

now use this path as

bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
Done now bundle install

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks a bunch. Might come back with more qs :D

Comment: @StelzenPieper Even though I appreciate your intentions avoid "thank you" comments. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment This would help you in your journey navigating the stackoverflow community guidelines.